# Pattern for global variables

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of variables in my application that I have to use in most of my closures, like variables holding preloaded requests, or variables holding the current state of application (that need to be changed dynamically in different places).

So my application structure looks like this:

```
(function() {
  var MainModule = (function () {

  })();
  var Utils = (function () {

  })();
  var Events = (function () {

  })();
})();
```

And I create these variable inside `MainModule`, but want to change them, remove them, etc, inside `Utils` and `Events`. I've been thinking about two ways:

1. Creating `Context` closure that keeps an array of those variables, and have `get()` and `set()` access methods.
2. Passing these variables to closures as arguments, but I coulnd't unset them and I'd have difficulties because of the way javascript passes arrays/objects to functions.

How should I handle it?

Comment: If you stop using those IIFE's your problem goes away, as then you'd have regular scoping.

Comment: What do you have in `MainModule`, `Utils` and `Events`?  It sounds like you have overly abstracted something, and are trying to make a class.

Comment: You could have a `MainModule.exposedVariable`. All other modules can see that.

Comment: Just use object properties instead of variables ("namespacing").

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  var MainModule = (function () {
      var mine;
      return {
         getMine: function(){ return mine; },
         setMine: function(a){ mine = a; }
      }

  })();
  var Utils = (function () {
      return function(module){
        module.getMine();
      }

  })();
  var Events = (function () {

  })();
})();
```

IIFE does not give anything to put into the MainModule variable so I'm assuming something else will be calling something within Utils. get/set is the safest way to give access to private variables. Like the comments said, IIFE should only be used when needed, otherwise it's just pointless abstraction.